Ошибка 500 при разворачивании сайта на удаленном сервере
Бекенд написан на NodeJS, фронтенд написан на ReactJS. Локально все работает, но при разворачивании на удаленном сервере и настройке nginx выдает 500 ошибку.
Настройки nginx:


server {
        listen 80;

        server_name api.vladimirstrashnov.ru;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/vladimirstrashnov.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/vladimirstrashnov.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
        listen 80;

        server_name vladimirstrashnov.ru;

        root /root/movies-explorer-frontend/build;

        location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/vladimirstrashnov.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/vladimirstrashnov.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot



До подключения домена POST и GET запросы отправлялись исправно.
Код фронтенда: https://github.com/strahpas1986/movies-explorer-frontend
Код бекенда: https://github.com/strahpas1986/movies-explorer-api
P.S. Настройку делал по инструкции из Яндекс.Практикума

Нужно почитать логи

Добавил логи nginx. Не могу понять что прописал не так?! Прописал также chmod +x толку никакого

Permission denied вам ни о чем не говорит? И, соответственно, сам вопрос: вы реально уверены, что ваш сайт должен располагаться в /root? Это домашняя директория для пользователя root - там остальным не то что записывать, - читать запрещено оттуда.
